# Search between two files in Python

Tags: python, file, search

I want to find those characters which are matched in between two files. In `file1.txt` I have `red green blue`, in `file2.txt` I have `green gray`, 
and I want the output:

```
green
```

I have already tried:

```
searchfile = open("file1.txt", "r")
      for line in searchfile:
         if "red" in line:
             print line
      searchfile.close()
```

But it prints the whole file contents. How can I get this output?

Comment: Characters? Or words? For characters common content is `green ` (see trailing space?), for words just `green`. Please clarify.

Comment: i want to find by words . i am very new in python

Comment: Are all your colors on a single line (i.e., are they `red green blue` or are they on multiple lines (`red\ngreen\nblue\n`)?  If they're on a single line, then that's going to give you the whole file contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked how to find the *characters* present in both files, however it seems from your expected input and output you actually want the *words* present in both files, delimited by a space.

```
set1 = set(open("a.txt").read().split())
set2 = set(open("b.txt").read().split())
print filter(lambda x: x in set1, set2)
```

prints

```
['green']
```

where `a.txt` contains

```
red green blue
```

and `b.txt` contains

```
green gray
```

**Don't read past here if you're not extraordinarily interested; this is the faster - and by far the prettier - approach.**

---

Since OP asked for alternative approaches, if you're *very* particular about time complexity, you could create a generator function:

```
whitespace = {' ','\n'}
def word_generator(file_object):
  str_list = []
  for char in file_object:
    if char not in whitespace:
      str_list.append(char)
    else:
      yield "".join(str_list)
      del str_list[:]

with open("a.txt") as f1, open("b.txt") as f2:
  set1 = set(word_generator(f1.read()))
  set2 = set(word_generator(f2.read()))
  print filter(lambda x: x in set1, set2)
```

This way you're not reading your file content into a string, splitting the string into a list and then constructing a set from the list. Instead, you are "splitting" the string on the fly, feeding the words directly to the set comprehension.

The cost is also lower (although extremely insignificantly) because you're only comparing each character to space and newline. `split` without any arguments compares against [space, tab, newline, return and formfeed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split). Like I said, extremely insignificant difference.

**[EDIT]**

While my reasoning around the complexity of the different approaches seem (to me at least) sound, the efficient C implementation of `split` seems to trump the gain of using a generator:

```
def split():
  set1 = set(open("a.txt").read().split())
  set2 = set(open("b.txt").read().split())
  lst = filter(lambda x: x in set1, set2)

def generator():

  whitespace = {' ','\n'}
  def word_generator(file_object):
    str_list = []
    for char in file_object:
      if char not in whitespace:
        str_list.append(char)
      else:
        yield "".join(str_list)
        del str_list[:]
  with open("a.txt") as f1, open("b.txt") as f2:
    set1 = set(word_generator(f1.read()))
    set2 = set(word_generator(f2.read()))
    lst = filter(lambda x: x in set1, set2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  from timeit import timeit
  print timeit("split()", setup="from __main__ import split", number=10000)
  print timeit("generator()", setup="from __main__ import generator", number=10000)
```

The above yields

```
0.103315830231
0.151041984558
```

as a result (near-identical proportions on numerous subsequent runs), so it seems you should go with the first, simpler approach. How relieving, that generator solution was really ugly.

If anyone has a different idea about why the first approach is faster, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: is there any other way to do this program ?? EvenLisle

Comment: There are several ways of doing it. Did you have anything particular in mind? @prtk

Comment: @prtk can't tell if sarcasm...was this not satisfactory? If there's anything unclear about my answer, I'd be more than happy to elaborate.

Comment: its is very much help able for me , thanks @EvenLisle

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1. For each file, make a list of colors using your current code and the split function
2. Build sets and compute intersection: s1 & s2